# Difference between In and During

Tags: prepositions, time

How different are the following two sentences:

> I am not allowed to sleep **during** the day.
>   I am not allowed to sleep **in** the day.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence with *during* is the correct one; the other one is incorrect.

The preposition *during* generally refers to a time interval in its *entirety*: in your example, the *entire* day (meaning "daytime") is a time interval in which sleep is forbidden.

The preposition *in* is sometimes useable for referring to a *small portion* of a time interval. It doesn't work in your example, and I apologize but I can't explain why. It may be that it is grammatically correct, but "in the day" just isn't generally used, and doesn't sound natural.

Some examples using *in* that are correct and natural:

> I will bring you to the doctor's office in the morning.
>
> The fireflies will come out in the summertime.
>
> We'll be on vacation in November.

This last example is a good one for the in vs. during contrast. If you say:

> We'll be on vacation during November.

then you mean you'll be on vacation for the entire month, not just for a few days.